# Sized-to-fit SwiftUI bottom sheet height issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, bottom-sheet

I want to make Sized-to-fit SwiftUI bottom sheet

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var presentSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap me") {
            presentSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) {
            BottomView()
        }
    }
}

struct BottomView: View {
    @State var detentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.")
        .padding(40)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .readHeight()
        .onPreferenceChange(HeightPreferenceKey.self) { height in
            detentHeight = height
        }
        .presentationDetents([.height(detentHeight)])
    }
}
```

I use preferenceKey to calculate sheet height :

```
struct HeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

private struct ReadHeightModifier: ViewModifier {
    private var sizeView: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear.preference(key: HeightPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.height)
        }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(sizeView)
    }
}

extension View {
    func readHeight() -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(ReadHeightModifier())
    }
}
```

All is working fine except when I put app in background and reopen it again, sheet height is back to 0

Any help to fix this issue ?